# convert file to dict where value is a code, e.g. PovScore(1,2)

Tags: python

I have following data (7MB) and it's stored in transpostion.txt:

```
{'0x2df54c975eb48346': [PovScore(Cp(+57), BLACK), 5], ...}
```

I did try

```py
with open("transposition.txt", "r") as file:
    x = file.readline()
    transposition = eval(x)
    del x
```

but the memory reaches 99% and then hangs. I did try with 1MB file, it immediately loads and set the string, but when print it's very slow (IDLE):

```
>>> with open("testfile.txt", "r") as file:
        x = file.read()

>>> x
Squeezed text (2000 lines)
```

`json` module can't parse JSON with code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    json.dumps({'a':PovScore(0,0)})
  File "C:\Users\asdfs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\asdfs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\asdfs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\asdfs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type PovScore is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Make PovScore serializable.

Comment: `with open("transposition.txt", "w") as file` Are you sure this is the exact code you tried?  Because that opens the file for _writing_, not _reading_...

Comment: @nicomp is it possible when need to parse and write to a 7MB file?

Comment: If you want to both parse (read) and write, you'll need to open the file in r+ mode

Comment: @winapiadmin  I would think so, but you'll have to make the effort and find out.

Answer (score 0):

@nicomp helped me finding the solution.

The code for writing:

```py
with open("transposition.txt", "w") as file:
    json.dump(transposition,file, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, indent=4)
```

For parsing:

```py
with open("transposition.txt") as file:
    transposition = json.load(file)
for x in transposition:
    if transposition[x][0]["relative"].get("cp")!=None:
        transposition[x][0] = PovScore(Cp(transposition[x][0]["relative"]["cp"]), transposition[x][0]["turn"])
    elif transposition[x][0]["relative"].get("moves")!=None:
        transposition[x][0] = PovScore(Mate(transposition[x][0]["relative"]["moves"]), transposition[x][0]["turn"])
```

Memory problem is also solved
as this speed test on `eval()` function and `json` module:
|  | `eval()`/7MB | `json`/100MB |
| ---- | ------ | ---- |
| Loading | hang the computer (not formatted) | immediately (formatted) |
| Writing | N/A | approximate: 2m |
| Memory | 99% | 60% |

Comment: Share a [example] of what worked for you.